# Retrieving serenity report from gitlab ci pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, serenity-bdd

Running serenity on the gitlab CI pipeline works fine and I see the test output status ok, on the Zalenium dashboard. However, if something doesnt work, then I would really like to see the detailed serenity report that it creates in the /site/serenity on the build runner. How do to this in yaml? I have tried artefact: report but serenity isnt an option. Has anyone got a recipe for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use after_script in gitlab to upload the serenity results in the artifact.

Below is the way I did in Maven Serenity Project

```
image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-8

build:   
  stage: build   
  script:
    - mvn compile

test:   
  stage: test   
  script:
    - mvn clean verify

  after_script:
    - rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    - apt-get update
    - apt-cache gencaches
    - apt-get install -y zip unzip
    - zip -r serenity_report.zip ./target/site/serenity

  artifacts:
    when: always
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - ./serenity_report.zip
```

***Results from Gitlab Pipeline would look like below and you can download the artifact to get index.html file from site/serenity folder***

Uploading artifacts for successful job
Uploading artifacts...
./serenity_report.zip: found 1 matching files and directories
Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... ok responseStatus=201
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded

Comment: the artifacts section does not work,gitlab complains that  This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs artifacts config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword

Comment: @SlickTester Your gitlab CI file would be invalid that's why you are getting error from gitlab. Make sure you format your gitlab yml file correctly and validate it.

Answer (score -1):

Use `pages` to upload static content to GitLab.
The content is then published as a website.

You must:

- Place any static content in a `public/ directory`.
- Define artifacts with a path to the `public/ directory`.

The following example moves all files from the root of the project to the `public/ directory`.

The `.public` workaround is so `cp` does not also copy `public/` to itself in an infinite loop: